# Passing an address inside a WordPress post to a Google Map elsewhere on the Page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-geocoder

Background: My client is building their own WordPress site (using a purchased feature-rich theme), and I'm modifying a child theme as necessary to achieve customizations she wants. The theme comes with a Page template that includes a full-width Google Map across the top, which pulls its marker from a single address set within the Theme Options. It's meant to be used for one main "Contact Us" page.

The client's business has several locations, and she wants each location's page to include such a map. (Example linked below.) It seems that the ideal solution would be the ability to specify an address within a shortcode in the Post, and have *that* set the map marker.

Here's how the theme makes the map (where `$mapAddress` is the address from the Theme Options):

```
    <?php
$mapAddress = ot_get_option( 'map_address' );
$mapHeight = ot_get_option( 'map_height' );
$mapContent = ot_get_option( 'map_content' );
?>
<section id="block-map-wrapper">
    <div id="block-map" class="clearfix">       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // Map Options
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            },
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: false,
            panControl: false,

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // The Map Object
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        var address = "";
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ "address" : "<?php echo $mapAddress; ?>" }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                address = results[0].geometry.location;

                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: address, 
                map: map,
                clickable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<?php echo $mapContent; ?>" });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

            }
        });

        });
        </script>

        <div id="map" class = "map" style = "width: 100%; height: <?php echo $mapHeight; ?>px"></div>
    </div><!-- #block-map -->
<div class="shadow-bottom"></div>
</section><!-- #block-map-wrapper -->
```

[Here's a test page](http://www.philadelphiaeyeglasslabs.com/PEL/locations/test-location/) using a custom Page template I've created. Right now it's using the same map code as above. (Edit: See update below.)

I've tried creating a shortcode that takes an address attribute and sets it as `$mapAddress`, but that didn't work. I believe it's because the map is already loaded by the time the Loop gets parsed. How can I tell Maps to "come back" to the post to get the proper address?

My specialty lies in HTML & CSS, but Javascript befuddles me fairly easily, so please be explicit when explaining implementation.

---

**Bonus**: A further goal is to have the locations' parent Page also include such a map, but have multiple markers representing the multiple locations. When taking more than one location, Google Maps only accepts latitude/longitude. I don't want my client to be concerned with coordinates, so I know there's got to be something I can do with [the geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) so she can just input a list of addresses instead (into the same, or similar, shortcode solution developed for my main question). But I am extra-clueless about how to do that.

---

### Update

Per Brett's point, I've updated my test template to just the HTML:

```
    <section id="block-map-wrapper">
    <div id="block-map" class="clearfix">       
        <div id="map" class = "map" style = "width: 100%; height: <?php echo $mapHeight; ?>px"></div>
    </div><!-- #block-map -->
<div class="shadow-bottom"></div>
</section><!-- #block-map-wrapper -->
```

and added all of the script into a shortcode, which is invoked at the beginning of the Post. You can see at the test page (linked above) how it is indeed writing the script in the Post, but the map is not being rendered in the `#map` div. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold back rendering the map until you have your target address, so take the entire script block and render it in the shortcode macro instead. That way you can correctly fill in the map_address and map_content from the arguments to the short code macro, instead of from the Theme Options. The only Theme Option that still makes sense here is the map_height.

Comment: Since the map container lives outside the Loop, I can't ask the shortcode to render that code block straight (inside the Post content) BUT... Would this potentially work?: Leave the HTML structure intact but empty, and make the shortcode use [jQuery .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to then insert all the script using the target address?

Comment: I've updated my question with leaving the HTML and inserting the script elsewhere, but it's not rendering the map.

Comment: Looking at your test page under Chrome Dev Tools shows that the JS is dying on this line: `jQuery(function($) { var replaced = $("h2").html().replace('View Project','View Coupon'); $("h2").html(replaced); });`

Comment: Oh! Aaand that's my fault - an attempt to change out some wording without having to modify another part of the theme. I'll have to take this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery block finds it's target div using get element by id, so it doesn't matter where on the page the JavaScript is placed.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even notice that. (My eyes just glaze over when presented with a large block of script.) That makes things a whole lot easier...